# Software to Merge Similar Texts Like in Google Docs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, google-docs

I'm developing a CMS where users can edit each others notes.

Google Docs has a great feature where people can independently edit the same note and merge their edits.

Is there a jQuery plugin that does something like that? More generally, is there any kind of software that does this for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't do this strictly with a piece of JavaScript. There will need to be some sort of persistent copy or even a micro versioning system on the server side. The JavaScript component would simply make AJAX calls (based on whatever criteria... probably not every keyup or that would be highly inefficient) periodically, which would simultaneously fetch other people's changes.

A websocket implementation could be even better, but websockets are still a relatively unknown and unsupported commodity.

Comment: +1. Thanks for your comments @Greg Pettit. Is there any particular software or resource you can refer me to?

Comment: I'm afraid not. My answer was perhaps a bit more generic than I would typically prefer; just wanted to make sure you weren't spending too much time looking for a jQuery plugin as a solution. :-) For what it's worth (not much), some people have formed entire business models around your idea, which might indicate that it's not trivial to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response @Greg Pettit. I will give you the accepted answer as nobody has come up with anything better and you're probably right in that there's no easy solution to this.